# Send text with html to mandrilapp

Tags: html, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm trying to send something like this to mandrill `"the force is <strong> strong </strong> in you"` so it's get rendered like "the force is  **strong**  in you" but it's not happening. I'm using mandrill template api and using handlebars.

Is there any way to achieve this? I know i could divide the text in 3 parts and put the `<strong>` tag directly in the template but i have lots of text and would need lots of time

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a handlebars thing. The solution is using triple braces instead of double {{{variable}}} instead of {{variable}}